# Ошибка с сертификатами при загрузке изображения

Tags: python-3.6

Пытаюсь загрузить изображение с помощью виджет AsyncImage в Kivy. Получаю вот такую простыню:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/data/data/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 1318, in do_open
    encode_chunked=req.has_header('Transfer-encoding'))
  File "/data/data/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1239, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/data/data/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1285, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/data/data/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1234, in endheaders
        self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/data/data/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1026, in _send_output
self.send(msg)
  File "/data/data/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 964, in send
self.connect()
  File "/data/data/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1400, in connect
server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "/data/data/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 401, in wrap_socket
_context=self, _session=session)
  File "/data/data/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 808, in __init__
self.do_handshake()
  File "/data/data/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 1061, in do_handshake
self._sslobj.do_handshake()
  File "/data/data/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 683, in do_handshake
self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:748)
```

Здесь дело не во фреймворке Kivy, я так понимаю, а в том, что какие-то библиотеки или дополнительные файлы не установлены на моей версии Python. Может, кто-то подскажет, какие именно?

Comment: Вам известен адрес, на который грузятся картинки? Если попытаться открыть сайт из этого адреса в обычном браузере, оно откроется? Возможно, сайт использует сертификаты Let's Encrypt, а ваше устройство ничего не знает про Let's Encrypt. Или же сертификаты на сервере, на котором расположен сайт, некорректно настроен (забыты промежуточные сертификаты, например)

Comment: Сайт ВКонтакте - vk.com

Comment: пробовали  простые запросы (`https://vk.ru`)? Какой самый простой запрос, который ломается? Пробовали разными инструментами запросы выполнять (requests, curl), с других платформ?

Comment: С других сайтов все грузит без проблем. На ПК работает даже с vk.com, но вот при запуске непосредственно из исходных текстов на мобильном устройстве с сайтом ВКонтакте возникают проблемы. Именно при загрузке изображений. API ВКонтакте я использую без проблем.

Answer (score 0):

Пока решил проблему отключением проверки сертификатов:

```
import ssl

ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context
```